# Multiple event listener without loops

Tags: javascript

I have the same structure in my project!

```
<!-- menu structure-->
   <nav class="menu">
       <a class="trigger" href="#">item</a>
       <a class="trigger" href="#">item</a>
       <a class="trigger" href="#">item</a>
       <a class="trigger" href="#">item</a>
       <a class="trigger" href="#">item</a>
   </nav>
```

I want to add a event listener to all triggers but the solutions I found are using loops, here is js

```
menuitens = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
menuitens.addEventListener("click", function (){});
```

Comment: But you always have to loop on that. Note: you can make prototype function to loop as free

Comment: You need to use a loop! I think you want something like jQuery with one line but jQuery also uses a loop internally.

Comment: You should use jQuery. It will look like this: `$('.trigger').on('click', function() {...});`

Comment: I don't see loops in your code

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: Add the event listener to some container instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a single event listener just bind it to the container instead:

```
document.querySelector('.menu').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!e.target.classList.contains('trigger')) return;

    alert('.trigger clicked');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t6frderh/

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to all click events on the container element:

```
document.querySelector(".menu").addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(e)
  {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('target'))
    {
      // do stuff ....
    }
  }
);
```